# empty field php submit link with other script

Tags: php, submit

I have a online questionnaires that I've link with a submit form, towards to send the infos of the user with the result to my email. It's work fine.

The only thing is that right now, the people can submit the result of the quizz without completing their personnal informations.

If you can help me with this, it will be wonderfull, What i would like, it that persons have to obligatory to complete their infos ( names,email,etc) to submit the results =).

I really appreciate your time,

Here is my Js, Where the #quesForm are the results, and the #responseMessage an other info that needs to be send :

```
$(function() {
   $('#quesForm').on('submit',function(e) { 
    e.preventDefault();
    var uname = $("input[name=username]").val(); 
    var uemail = $("input[name=email]").val();
        var msg = $("input[name=message]").val()
    $.post('submit.php',{username:uname,email:uemail,message:msg,results:$('#resultKeeper').html(),subject:'Subject of your e-mail'},function(result){
   $('#responseMessage').html(result);
    });
  });
```

Here is my submit.php

```
   <?php $name = $_POST['username'];
   $email = $_POST['email'];
   $message = $_POST['message'];
   $results = $_POST['results'];
   $results = strip_tags($results); // add this to remove html tags and all
   $formcontent="From: $name \n Email: $email \n Phone: $message \n Results: \n $results";        
   $recipient = "email@email.com";
   $subject = "subject of email";
   $mailheader = "From: $email \r\n";
   mail($recipient, $subject, $formcontent, $mailheader) or die("Error!");
   echo "";
   ?>
```

Answer (score 0):

Check for empty fields before you submit the form:

```
$(function() {
   $('#quesForm').on('submit',function(e) { 
    e.preventDefault();
    var uname = $("input[name=username]").val(); 
    var uemail = $("input[name=email]").val();
    var msg = $("input[name=message]").val()

    //check for empty fields
    if(uname==''||uemail==''||msg==''){
    return
    }
    $.post('submit.php',{username:uname,email:uemail,message:msg,results:$('#resultKeeper').html(),subject:'Subject of your e-mail'},function(result){
   $('#responseMessage').html(result);
    });
  });
```

Do the same in php as well if this is important

Comment: yes . ..  how to do that in php ? thank you already for the js =)